# An error occurred while installing bcrypt 3.1.7 and bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bcrypt, bitnami, bcrypt-ruby

I'm using rubystack2.2.0. When I run bundle install for a new project that uses bcrypt, I'm getting this error:

Installing bcrypt 3.1.7 with native extensions

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
```

and here is the verbose output

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/ws/sachilig-sjc/new/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150709-16222-82kbqs.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/util.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Argument "UUUUUUUUUUUU" isn't numeric in division (/) at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Illegal division by zero at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/File/Basename.pm line 52.
Compilation failed in require at /router/bin/make line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /router/bin/make line 37.

make "DESTDIR="
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Argument "UUUUUUUUUUUU" isn't numeric in division (/) at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
Illegal division by zero at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/warnings.pm line 390.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/perl/lib/5.16.3/File/Basename.pm line 52.
Compilation failed in require at /router/bin/make line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /router/bin/make line 37.

make failed, exit code 255

Gem files will remain installed in /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /ws/sachilig-sjc/new/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/bcrypt-3.1.7/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.7' succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: "Make sure that gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.7' succeeds before bundling." did you?

Comment: Yes @Braiam. It's giving   this in the beginning. 
  Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
   ERROR:  Error installing bcrypt:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
and the rest of the error is same as the above.

Answer (score 3):

It helped me to replace the `gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'` with `gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'` in the Gemfile of my rails application.

The difference is that the bundler can load any gem that varies with the last (minor) number.

Then I run `bundle install` from the command line and it works like miracle.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had this same problem and I may have solved it using 
`rm -rf Gemfile.lock`

, then remove the version information from your Gemfile and then try to run
`gem install bcrypt`
see if that works... if so:
`bundle`
`bundle update`
if that doesn't work then you have the wrong version of `ruby -v` or `rails -v`. In which case you may have to `rbenv install Ruby` then `gem install Rails`.
I'm not sure what my exact order of events was for things like that but I kept doing things like this and eventually something gave in.

By the way your ruby is definitely not the most up to date at 2.2.0 so you probably want to go and install ruby..
https://gorails.com has some stuff.

Comment: Thanks. I removed Gemfile.Lock , it didn't work out. I'm using rubystack 2.2.0 by bitnami. It comes with ruby 2.2.0 and rails 4.2.3.