# Bcrypt error when installing the devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When trying to run **bundle install** after adding
`gem 'devise', '~> 4.8', '>= 4.8.1'` in Gemfile will show the below error

**An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.18), and Bundler cannot continue.**

Are there any steps before using it?

**Rails** 7.0.4

**ruby** 3.1.2

Please how can solve I it?
Thank you

Comment: Did you checked this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330528/an-error-occurred-while-installing-bcrypt-3-1-7-and-bundler-cannot-continue ? if this helps.

Comment: do try to install the `bcrypt` gem manually, then you can get the log file, and look to see what the errors will be (I'm assuming missing libraries)

Comment: Hi @RahulSingh Yes I was check the link but didn't solve my problem

Comment: Hi @Jad No things in logs and I trying  to install bcrypt manually still get same error

Comment: It should give you the path to the specific log files you need to check in the error message. Can you go back and check what the error messages say?

Answer (score -1):

Additional logs would be helpful next time.

For me such issue happened due to missing `mkdir` executable in `/usr/bin` folder. Moreover, installation of all `bcrypt` alternatives failed too. I mean:

- argon2
- scrypt

The fix was pretty easy:

```
sudo ln -s `which mkdir` /usr/bin/mkdir
```

which create a symbolic link in `/usr/bin` directory to the actual executable.

Due to lack of context, I can't  be sure if my solution applies to your situation. At the same time, I didn't find this solution on StackOverflow so I just want to share what I found.